# Java Playwright get response body of redirect

Tags: java, playwright, playwright-java

Im using https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-java.

This code:

```java
final BrowserContext context = browser.newContext();
final Page page = context.newPage();
page.onResponse(response -> {

    response.body();
    
});
```

gives the exception: `Response body is unavailable for redirect responses`, when a redirect occurred. Is there a way to get the response body regardless?

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe help you.

```
final BrowserContext context = browser.newContext();
final Page page = context.newPage();
page.onResponse(response -> {
page.request().get(response.url()).body();
});
```